# Timer lagging behind

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, timer

I want to have a running timer in my app which displays the seconds elapsed upto 2 decimal places e.g. 2.31 seconds. I'm using `System.Threading.Timer` for this and I'm setting the `Timer` object to call `refreshTimeBox()` function every 10 milliseconds (because I want the seconds upto 2 decimal places). But, the timer lags behind. And as the time passed increases, it lags more and more behind. I'm guessing its because `refreshTimeBox()` is taking too long to complete. But, I also tried calling `refreshTimeBox()` every 100 milliseconds instead. The timer still lags. The only difference is that the lag becomes noticeable after a longer time in this case than in the case where I use 10 milliseconds as interval. I have the following code to initialize the timer:

```
timer = new Timer(refreshTimeBox, null, 0, 10);
```

The following is the code for `refreshTimeBox`:

```
public void refreshTimeBox(object param)
{
    time += 0.01f;
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(WriteTimeBox);
}
```

The following is the code for `WriteTimeBox`:

```
public void WriteTimeBox()
{
    TimeBar.Text = time.ToString("0.00");
}
```

`time` is the variable which stores the time elapsed and `TimeBar` is the text box which is being updated.

I want as accurate a timer as possible. Please help me with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to display the amount of time that has elapsed since a particular event in the past, then the best way to do that is to store the time at "time zero", e.g. `startTime`, and then, in your timer event, computer the time that has elapsed by subtracting `startTime` from the current time, and displaying the difference.

You can't rely on timer events being delivered at exact intervals. This isn't a realtime system. Added to which, you should be aware that `BeginInvoke` is likely requesting that the method call occur on a different thread to the current one, and that different thread may not be able to dispatch that method call at the current time.

Comment: Actually, I need a running timer. So, I guess what I can do is still use a timer to call the `refreshTimeBox` function at intervals of 10 milliseconds. But, instead of adding 0.01 to time variable, I could calculate the difference in time since the last timer event. Would that be good?

Comment: Basically this would work BUT use UTC for such calculations - otherwise you might end up with "negative differences" in certain situation because of DST or similar aspects!

Comment: @Divya - you'll accumulate errors if you try to calculate how long the actual intervals were - the only reasonable accurate way to know how long has actually elapsed overall is to calculate it from the start time. We might do better if you told us the overall goal.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - I'm just making a game where I need to show how much time has elapsed. So, I want to have a running timer at the bottom of the screen so that the player knows how much time has gone by. One play of the game would almost never be longer than a minute. So, I think a minute is too short a time to accumulate errors. I changed my code as you suggested and it works great - good enough for the purposes of my app. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 3):

You could also use a stopwatch

```
        System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw=new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
```

And in the update function

```
        TimeBar.Text = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
```

Then you don't have to worry about UTC issues

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know there was such an easy way to do this. :)

Answer (score 1):

Timers always have the possibility of lagging. What you need to do is store when you started, then compare it to the current time.

```
private DateTime startTime;
public void startTimer() {
    startTime = DateTime.Now;
}

public void refreshTimeBox(object param)
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(WriteTimeBox);
}

public void WriteTimeBox()
{
    TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Now - startTime;
    // See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ecy8h51.aspx for TimeSpan formatting.
    TimeBar.Text = ts.time.ToString("s.ff");
}
```